# Assembly code to execution graph visualization

Tags: c++, data-visualization, graphs, assembly

is there a software or lib that visualizes generated assembly (preferred) or C++/C code to a directed graph, witch in turn shows the paths of execution. Something similar like the example in the picture (This is from Godbolt.) .

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

(Update)
I want the assembly code to be divided into blocks, and the function calls to be represented in a graph format. This would resemble an assembly compilation cycle graph. The issue lies in the inlines and attributes from GCC/G++, which create various shortcuts, leading to significant loss of clarity. Optimization exacerbates the problem, making it even more obscure. However, with the right adjustments in the code and the use of volatile, assembly instructions, the assembly code would become more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, then GCOV springs to mind. Then you want a GUI to display the results, and I [Gcovr](https://gcovr.com/en/stable/) might be what you want.

Is this what you are after?   As you can see, every line except line 7 is executed (1 time).

[image]

As you can see here, it shows how many times each line is executed:
[image]

Comment: Hm ok, but this does not give me a graph of execution. But I did not know that GCOV is able to do this. This is one more item that could help.

Comment: What are you looking for? Something like a call tree?

Comment: And, do you want something static or dynamic? Static all tree is simple - DoxyGen. I would like something that would take the output of GCOV and generate a dynamic call tree. Is that what you want?

Comment: What I want is the same thing that godbolt gives you when you ask for the graph visualization. Just I do not want mine code to be on Godbolt.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question to reflect that? Maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: My idea is people are working with different things so they can brainstorm maybe they have a good idea. Yours is also not bad.

Comment: I have marked this question as a favourite; I hope that you get an answer - so that I can use it too :-)

Comment: Four years later, and I finally looked at https://godbolt.org/  What are you trying to do? When you say "path of execution", do you mean the path taken through the code at run-time? I don't see how to do that with GodBolt. Although it does show the difference in assembler produced by two compilers for the same source code, which is neat